# Picture element has bigger height than the img

Tags: html, css, image

Why is the picture element bigger than the image element? (The red line at the bottom of the sample) - chrome 88. How can I prevent that?

```css
picture{
  background-color: red;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeyM8.jpg" media="all">
  <img src="">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because as an inline-element, the image is vertically aligned at the baseline, which leaves some space below it. Just add `display: block` to the image to avoid that.

```css
picture{
  background-color: red;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeyM8.jpg" media="all">
  <img src="">
</picture>
```